# Playing ffmpeg converted video on Google slides

Tags: video, ffmpeg, google-slides

I have a PNG image and an MP3 audio file. I'd like to create a video with a still image and use it in a Google slides presentation. From Google's documentation, these formats (and codecs) are supported: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423694?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop

1) FFMPEG is the easiest tool I can find to make a video from image + audio. But if you have other options, please suggest.
2) I tried a couple commands:

```
## Command 1
ffmpeg -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -acodec mp3 -vcodec flv1 video9.flv

## Command 2
ffmpeg -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 video7.mov

## Command 3
ffmpeg -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -vcodec wmv1 final14.wmv
```

But all of these display the error `Video cannot be played` in Google slides. When I try to play them in Google drive, I get the error `Unable to process this video`.

Any thoughts on how I can produce a video file that'll play in Google slides?

Answer (score 1):

H.264 video & AAC audio in MP4:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

General compatibility suggestions:

- Make sure the image is looping with the `-loop` input option; otherwise it will encode one frame. When `-loop` is included you will also need the `-shortest` option so it doesn't loop forever.
- Include `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) to output a compatible pixel format.
- Use AAC instead of MP3 in MP4 for better player compatibility.
- If the device/player is old and doesn't like the video add `-profile:v main`. Otherwise omit this. Or include it for mass compatibility for playability on arbitrary legacy devices.
- `-movflags +faststart` will allow it to begin playing before the video is completely downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out how to play a video generated by ffmpeg, but I used an online image + video converter (http://ez-converter.com/) and the output from that seemed to work in Google play slides. Would love to know why ffmpeg converted videos weren't working though if anyone has insight